# How to make a multiple columns in an SQL Database table unique

Tags: sql

Is it possible to alter a table so that the row as a whole (excluding the IDENTIFIER (ID) ) can only be inserted once in the database?
For example; you have a Start and End timestamp for an Employee, and you want other employees to be able to have the same Start and End value, but you don't want the same Employee to be able to inserted twice the same Start and End value?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Perhaps you also want to reject overlapping periods for an employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a unique constraint or index for the rest of the rowsin the column:

```
alter table t add constraint t_unique_all unique (employee, start, end)
```